# powershell copies .xlsm as a folder instead of .xlsm

Tags: powershell, copy

In powershell one line of code aims to copy a .xlsm file to another directory.  However, on some machines (all windows 10) the file will copy as an empty folder while other machines copy correctly as a .xlsm file.

Here's the code:

copy-item "$file_location\filename.xlsm" -destination "$new_file_location\filename.xlsm"

Is there a way to force the copy-item command to keep the file type intact?  Any idea why some machines will copy correctly and not others?  Maybe there's a better way to do this copy that's more robust?

Thanks!

Comment: If you add `-Container:$false`, do you have more predictable results?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using on the systems where the file copies as a folder?

Comment: Does the destination folder exist?

Comment: Adding -Container:$false had no affect.

Comment: I changed the line to:  copy-item "$file_location\filename.xlsm" -container:$false -destination "$new_file_location\filename.xlsm"

Comment: both machines (one works and one doesn't) are running the same version of powershell.  PSVersion, PSedition, Buildversion, CLRVersion, WSManstackversion, psremotingprotocolversion, and serializationversion are all identical

Comment: yes, the destination folder exists

Comment: Problem is stupid user error - I forgot to put in the file name after the file_location.  smdh.  sorry to waste your time.